# Is there a jQuery method or hack for reseting a div's properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, reset

Is there a method (in jQuery as I assume) that would "reset" elements - restore a `div` to the state that it was at the beginning, without reloading the page? I have some animations on child elements and writing a function for reversing each of them would be quite laborious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the state of the `div`  with [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attributes and retentive when needed.

Ex:

```
$("divId").attr("AtSomePoint", "ThisisTheClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the affected elements' `style` attribute.

`$("#divId").removeAttr("style")`